# jquery mobile geolocation

Tags: jquery, mobile, geolocation

simple question.. how do I set a redirect if the user selects not allow for the geolocator pop up? If allow and error I have covered. works fine. But I' not sure how to set the not allow selection.

```
function showLocation(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      //window.location = "/restaurant/latitude/40.714269/longitude/-74.005972/";
      window.location = "/restaurant/";
    }

    function errorHandler(err) {
      if(err.code == 1) {
            alert("Error: Can not access!");
      }else if( err.code == 2) {
            alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
      }
    }
    function getLocation(){

       if(navigator.geolocation){
          // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
          var options = {timeout:60000};
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
       }else{
          alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [W3C Geolocation API spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/), the error handler should be invoked with the appropriate reason for the failure. This includes permission denied by the user.

Unfortunately, it seems like there is a [bug/feature in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650247) where if you select `Not Now` from the popup, nothing happens - the error handler is not called. However, if you select `Never Share`, your error handler does get called and with the code you posted, you'll see the alert saying `Error: Can not access!`.

There is no third option in Chrome (only `Allow` and `Deny`) and things seem to work just fine there.

Also see [How to detect negative user response for geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380195/how-to-detect-negative-user-response-for-geolocation) where a solution is proposed (it involves using a timeout to detect that nothing has happened and treating it the same as permission denied)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have tried setting the window.location. Why does that not work for you?

window.location = "../nonGeoLocationPage.html"

Comment: That works.. I didn't realize no access/error 1 was in actuallity a do not allow selection..