# navigator.geolocation.watchPosition How do I open and center map on preset coordinates if user denies geolocation access

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

http://rickgutierrez.bol.ucla.edu/map_mobile6.htm

The map is set up to load centered on the users current location. If the user denies the geolocation request, the map is not opening. How do I get the map to open on

center: new google.maps.LatLng( 34.05221496568917, -118.24334979057312 ),

if the user denies the geolocator access to their location? Right now I have an error function that opens a prompt with an error message when the geolocation is denied or fails. I am guessing that I should replace that function with a function that has the above coordinates but how do I feed those to the function that creates the map and centers it on those coordinates?

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to set the center for the map in all the error paths that execute when geocoding is denied or fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom position-object from the desired coordinates:

```
{coords:{latitude:34.05221496568917,longitude: -118.24334979057312}}
```

You now may call displayLocation with that object as argument, e.g:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(  
      displayLocation, 
      function(){displayLocation({coords:{latitude:34.05221496568917,
                                          longitude: -118.24334979057312}})
      }
);
```

You should also take a look at this: [How to detect negative user response for geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380195/how-to-detect-negative-user-response-for-geolocation)

Comment: I already have a displayLocation function that receives the navigator.geolocation.watchPosition coordinates. I attempted to add the function you suggested with the coordinates to navigator.geolocation.watchPosition, just like you have above. This didn't work

Comment: I also tried creating another displayLocation function but called it centerLocation.                                                           centerLocation = function( position ) {
    map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude ) );
    
   }; This also did not work

Comment: What can I say, I tried my suggestion (with chrome), and it works as expected with getCurrentPosition and also with watchPosition

Comment: Okay. I think I figured out part of the error. My navigator.geolocation.watchPosition function is wrapped in a function that checks for an iphone or android. I was making the changes there. If the function is not on an android or iPhone it runs a getCurrentPosition function. Of course I am testing all this on a desktop browser and none of the changes were working. Now that I made the changes you suggested in that part of the function I am getting it to open on those coordinates. Thanks.

Comment: I got it all figured out now. I left the displayLocation function as is, then added a new function currentLocation = function( position ) {
    map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng( 34.05221496568917, -118.24334979057312 ) );
    
   }                                                                this function just sets centers the maps on the coordinates I wanted and leaves out the blinking blue marker. Thanks so much for your help!!